# save mysql data to sql file using php, ready to import into sqlite

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I have a script that generates a sql file from the data saved in a mysql database.
The data is stored in the mysql database without any added slashes.
This all works fine except for quotes.
If there is a quote in the mysql data then the file is generated, but it wont then insert the data into sqlite. 
I have tried adding slashes to the data that is extracted and put into the sql file, but this doesn't work.. Is there a correct procedure to do this, or a better way to get data from mysql into sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

Why not dump the data via mysql itself rather than PHP code?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Thanks developerwjk, however the php is generating the code fine, it is when it comes to installing it on sqlite, the errors are occuring becuase of the quotes. I am just trying to find how one should instal sql file with quotes in the data